# Model does not update after manual DB deletion

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I get my account managers like this.

```
            AccountManagers =
                p.SuperUserAccessPermissions
                .AsQueryable()
                .Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false)
                .Select(SuperUserAccessPermissionViewModel)
                .ToList()
```

Note `a.IsDeleted == false`.

However, when I delete it manually from my DB and try to display it in a view like this:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.AccountManagers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FullName</td>
                <td class="w1">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                       href="@Url.Route(Routes.SuperArea.Clients.ModalDeleteAccountManagerGET(item.SuperUserAccessPermissionId))"
                       @Html.DataAttribute_Modal(ModalType.Medium)>
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

I still get it in a list. Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the `p` in your `p.SuperUserAccessPermissions`? Why do you need an `.AsQueryable()` on there?

Comment: I delete it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: And you ran a separate query in Management Studio to confirm it was actually set to IsDeleted = 1?

Comment: @@Irmantas Želionis, are you using any `IoC` pattern like Unity?

Comment: @ ershoaib no, I am not

Comment: could you please add the code for `p` also in question?

Comment: `That user does not exist anymore. Not sure what to check` Run `SELECT * FROM SuperUserAccessPermissions WHERE ID = TheOneYouDeleted` from Management Studio. What is the value of `IsDeleted`?

Comment: Please show us the action code where you render the above view.

Answer (score -1):

First, delete the record from database via script:

```
UPDATE [table] SET IsDeleted = true
```

Second, just to be sure, select the record you just deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE IsDeleted = true
```

If the record is really deleted, start the application and monitor the table for any new entries. There is a possibility that your application inserts new record somewhere from the code.

If the record is still there, I would check the connection string. It happened to me more times that I would like to admit that the application was connected to the wrong database.

Comment: The OP is clearly using a soft-delete to remove the row.  `DELETE FROM....` is not what he is doing or wants to do.